# Null Pointer Exception In Paypal Express Checkout And also give blank page

Tags: java, jsp, paypal

In Express Checkout that total is display but product name and other details not showing 
    and give error NUll pointer Exception and add the '=' then showing  blank

```
public HashMap CallShortcutExpressCheckout(String item, String paymentAmount, String currencyCodeType, String paymentType, 
                                            String returnURL, String cancelURL,
                                            HttpSession session)
{
    session.setAttribute("paymentType", paymentType);
    session.setAttribute("currencyCodeType", currencyCodeType);

    /* 
    Construct the parameter string that describes the PayPal payment
    the varialbes were set in the web form, and the resulting string
    is stored in $nvpstr
    */
    String nvpstr = "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=" + paymentAmount + "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=" + paymentType + "&ReturnUrl=" + URLEncoder.encode( returnURL ) + "&CANCELURL=" + URLEncoder.encode( cancelURL ) + "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=" + currencyCodeType;

         nvpstr=nvpstr+ "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0="+item;
         nvpstr=nvpstr+ "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0="+item;
          nvpstr=nvpstr+ "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0="+item;
         System.out.println("item="+item);
    /* 
    Make the call to PayPal to get the Express Checkout token
    If the API call succeded, then redirect the buyer to PayPal
    to begin to authorize payment.  If an error occured, show the
    resulting errors
    */
        System.out.println("amountpay="+paymentAmount);
        HashMap nvp = httpcall("SetExpressCheckout", nvpstr);
    String strAck = nvp.get("ACK").toString();
    if(strAck !=null && strAck.equalsIgnoreCase("Success"))
    {
        session.setAttribute("TOKEN", nvp.get("TOKEN").toString());
    }

    return nvp;
}
```

and showing blank expresscheckout.jsp

Comment: show us the stack trace

Comment: arning:   StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.jsp.expresscheckout_jsp._jspService(expresscheckout_jsp.java:520)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)

Comment: I guess the problem is in your jsp.